# PowerShell create remote instance of IE with Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to spawn an IE instance remotely via PowerShell.

```
Invoke-Command -computername foo -scriptblock {
    $ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
    $ie.Visible = $true
    $ie.Navigate("http://duckduckgo.com")
}
```

It spawns the instance, I can see it in processes but it doesn't become visible to to the user. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are not doing anything wrong.

As far as I understand, It's just not possible to interact with a remote user's desktop through PSRemoting.

If Powershell cannot do this, Microsoft's (previously Sysinternal's) tool PSEXEC can do this (take a look at the -i parameter).